# Converting an array to hash - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following array and I want to convert it a hash with keys as age and values like the name of the person. Additionally, I want to make sure that folks of the same age belong to the same key.

```rb
ages = [ ['alpha', 20], ['beta',21], ['charlie',23], ['delta', 20] , ['gamma', 23]]
```

how do I convert the above into a hash like below?

eg - `{20 => ['alpha','delta'] }` etc.

i have tried the following code but i am getting stuck beyond this point:

```
hash = Hash[ages.collect {|item| [item[1], item[0]]} ]
```

pp hash

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions is to use:

```rb
hash = ages.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |obj, res|
  res[obj.last] << obj.first
end

=> {20=>["alpha", "delta"], 21=>["beta"], 23=>["charlie", "gamma"]}
```

1. [`Hash#default_proc`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc)
2. [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to do this: [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) with [Enumerable#group_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by)

```
ages.
  group_by(&:second).
  transform_values { |entries| entries.map(&:first) }
# => {20=>["alpha", "delta"], 21=>["beta"], 23=>["charlie", "gamma"]}
```

Comment: `&:second`? Was there a rails tag previously?

Comment: Hah I can't remember what's in rails vs ruby to be honest. And this answer also relies on active support methods as I said.

Comment: `group_by` is ruby `Enumerable` not `ActiveSupport`

Comment: thanks ... like i said, i can't keep track, but that's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

you can create the hash first and loop through the ages collecting members of similar ages into arrays.

```
hash = Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=Array.new()}
ages.each do |age|
  hash[age.last]<<age.first
end
p hash #{20=>["alpha", "delta"], 21=>["beta"], 23=>["charlie", "gamma"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ages.each_with_object({}) do |(str,x),h|
  (h[x] ||= []) << str
end
  #=> {20=>["alpha", "delta"], 21=>["beta"], 23=>["charlie", "gamma"]}
```

`h[x] ||= []` expands to

```
h[x] = h[x] || []
```

If `h` does not have a key `x` this becomes

```
h[x] = nil || []
```

causing `h[x]` to be set equal to an empty array, after which `h[x] << str` is executed.

Expressing the block variables as `|(str,x),h|` makes use of Ruby's [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
enum = ages.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["alpha", 20], ["beta", 21], ["charlie", 23],
  #     ["delta", 20], ["gamma", 23]]:each_with_object({})> 
(str,x),h = enum.next
  #=> [["alpha", 20], {}] 
str
  #=> "alpha" 
x #=> 20 
h #=> {} 
(h[x] ||= []) << str
  #=> ["alpha"] 

(str,x),h = enum.next
  #=> [["beta", 21], {20=>["alpha"]}]
```

and so on.

Comment: How about `h[x]= [*h[x],str]` instead :). I know it makes a bunch of discarded Arrays it just looks so fun